# Ideal Class Number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $R$ and $S$ are both Dedekind domain and $R$ is a subring of $S$ then can we
show $\mathfrak{cl}(S)=1$ implies $\mathfrak{cl}(R)=1$ ? Is it true?
Also, is there any relation or theorem for us to determine the class number
between those rings and subrings.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think there are many examples of number fields of class number not 1 with extensions of class number 1 (but I don't know offhand where to find one).

Comment: What was the point of the edit replacing "Cl" with "$\mathfrak{cl}$"?

Comment: Just standard notation and use of the possibilities of MathJax to improve the presentation of the question

Comment: I've never seen "$\mathfrak{cl}$" in fraktur...

Comment: Many thanks for the comments and the edit. Any answers will be appreciated!

Comment: Take for instance $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]\subset\Bbb{R}$. The class number of $\Bbb{R}$ is $1$ while $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is not a unique factorisation domain hence not a principal ideal domain and its class number is $\gt 1$

Comment: Thanks @marwalix  but Z[\sqrt(5)] is not Dedekind domain.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]\subset \Bbb{C}$ is what I meant. Sorry, but it is not convenient on a smartphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can always embed a domain in its field of fractions. So take some Dedekind domain with nontrivial class group, something like $\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{-5}]$, and then embed it in $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{-5})$. But this is probably not what you have in mind, since a field is a very uninteresting example of a Dedekind domain.

(As usually $\operatorname{Cl} (K)$ denotes $\operatorname{Pic} (\mathcal{O}_K)$, this might be confusing. What I mean is that $\operatorname{Pic} (K)$ is trivial for any field $K$, while for $\mathcal{O}_K \subset K$ the group $\operatorname{Pic} (\mathcal{O}_K)$ is very often nontrivial. In particular, for $K = \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{-5})$.)

For a nontrivial example, one can look at [quadratic subfields of cyclotomic fields](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numberfield/discquad.html). For instance, $\mathbb{Q} (\zeta_{20})$ contains $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{-5})$, and while $h_{\mathbb{Q} (\zeta_{20})} = 1$, we have $h_{\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{-5})} = 2$.

Comment: Thank you very much. So is there any properties like surjectivity or exact sequence for Picard group of those rings and subrings?
Or under certain assumptions this may hold?

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279853/the-picard-brauer-short-exact-sequence

Comment: @Alejo is there additional conditions on $S$ such that the principality propagates down to $R$ ? The class number is conserved ?

Answer (score 1):

Ken Yamamura, The determination of the imaginary abelian number fields with class number one, Math. Comp. 62 (1994) 899-921, has a table of the 172 imaginary abelian number fields with class number one. Looking through this table, it's easy to find examples that have subfields that don't have class number one. For example, ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt5)$ has class number one, and contains ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-15})$, which doesn't; similarly, ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-1},\sqrt5)$ versus ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-5})$; ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt2)$ versus ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-6})$; ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-7},\sqrt5)$ versus ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-35})$; and so on.

I believe the paper is freely available [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1994-62-206/S0025-5718-1994-1218347-3/S0025-5718-1994-1218347-3.pdf).